# Smooth proper local model of a smooth projective curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Say I have a curve $C/K$, where $K$ is a number field. Let $v$ be a place of $K$, and denote by $K_v$ the $v$-adic completion of $K$. Further assume $C$ is smooth and proper over $K$. Denote by $C_v$ the base change of $C$ to $K_v$.

My question is: is there necessarily a smooth and proper **integral** model for $C_v$?

Comment: What do you mean by curve? Is $C$ geometrically connected over $K$? If so, then $C_v$ is a smooth proper geometrically connected (hence geometrically integral) curve over $K$. Embed it into projective space over $K_v$ and embed the latter in $\mathbb{P}^n_O$. Take the closure of $C_v$ in the latter. This is an integral proper model. You can resolve singularities and get a regular proper integral model, but a smooth proper model is not necessarily guaranteed.

Comment: If $R$ is the valuation ring of $K_v$, then when I say integral model I mean a curve $\mathcal{C}_v$ over $R$, which becomes isomorphic to $C_v$ upon base change via $R\longrightarrow K_v$.

Comment: If you are asking that $C_v$ be *smooth* proper scheme over $Spec \, R$, then *no* not in general. In classical language, you need good reduction at $v$. But maybe you want something weaker?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the classical language; typically I think when someone says "good reduction at $v$", what one means is that the curve $C$ has an integral model $\mathcal{C}$ over $\mathcal{O}(K)$ (the ring of integers of $K$), which has good reduction at $v$. Assuming that, how do you go as far as showing that $C_v$ has a smooth integral model (over $R$)?

Comment: I guess I am asking if the moduli space of genus $g$, smooth proper plane curves over $R$, $\mathcal{M}_g$, is proper.

Comment: Have a look at Liu's book on arithmetic curves and algebraic geometry. In it he explains fairly well the following fact: If $X$ is a smooth proper geometrically connected curve over a number field $K$ and $v$ is a finite place, then $X$ has good reduction at $v$ if and only if 1) $X$ has a proper flat model over $O_K$ whose fibre over $k(v)$ is smooth  iff 2)  $X_{K_v}$ has a smooth proper model over $O_{K_v}$ iff 3) $X$ has a smooth proper model over $O_{K,v}$ (the local ring at $v$).

Comment: Re your final comment: The moduli space $M_g$ is not proper.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is precisely what I needed.